# create OpenCL project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda, project, opencl, nvidia

Can someone give me a step by step instruction of how to create an OpenCL project in Visual Studio 2010. I have downloaded the newest version of CUDA Toolkit (which is 5.0) and followed  this tutorial [[http://opencl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=OpenCL%20Tutorials%20-%200&referringTitle=OpenCL%20Tutorials]](http://opencl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=OpenCL%20Tutorials%20-%200&referringTitle=OpenCL%20Tutorials)

but now I am stuck. At the point where I need to configure the dependencies, I can't do it because I don't have `\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK\OpenCL\common\inc` folders in the `NVIDIA Corporation` folder in ProgramFiles (where I installed the toolkit). I also searched some opencl.lib file in the folders that I have, but can't find it. 
If someone can help me, I would appreciate it. Thx

Comment: The CUDA Toolkit 5.0 contains the headers in include\CL and the libraries lib\<platform>\OpenCL.lib. The same includes and library are available from AMD, Intel, Khronos, ... In the tutorial you are following simply replace Step 2 substeps 1,2,3 with the paths I mentioned.

Comment: Thank u, that worked. Please post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CUDA Toolkit 5.0 contains the headers in include\CL and the libraries lib\\OpenCL.lib. The same includes and library are available from AMD, Intel, Khronos, ... In the tutorial you are following simply replace Step 2 substeps 1,2,3 with the paths I mentioned.

Comment: One more thing. Following the previous mentioned tutorial, in the third step I need to add: OpenCL.lib, shrUtils32D.lib, oclUtils32D.lib, but the last two are not there. Do you know where I can find them. Thank u for your trouble.

Comment: shrUtils32D.lib and oclUtils32D.lib are utility libraries used by the NVIDIA Compute SDK. These libraries are not necessary for writing OpenCL programs. I would encourage you not to use these libraries as they were developed to simply the SDK samples not to be used by other developers.